difference between "personally know anyone" and "know anyone"
(1) I don't personally know anyone who works at an employment agency.
(2) I don't know anyone who works at an employment agency.
My non-native friends think "know anyone" doesn't make any sense. You have to add "personally". I don't understand why you need it. Can someone explain that?

Your non-native friends are wrong. Both sentences make perfect sense. However the addition of 'personally' does change the meaning. I encourage you for your own benefit to look up an English dictionary and research the word, then come back to us if you have further questions.

(1) is usually said together with another statement like " ... but my cousin says his nextdoor neighbor used to date a guy who worked at one."  There is some indirect (sometimes very indirect) knowledge. "I don't personally know anything about the food at that restaurant, but some co-workers go there for lunch and say it's very good."

Adding "personally" is often done to communicate a more intimate relationship. "I can get you a reservation at that restaurant; I'm a personal friend of the chef." Or "Oh, it's a good restaurant; I know the chef. I mean, I don't know him personally, but we've met."
It can also be done to emphasize that what you are about to say is your individual point of view or experience. "Personally, I think employment agencies are useless." Or "I know people rely on employment agencies, but personally I've had bad luck with them."
Adding "personally" could be useful if your meaning is one of these, but it's certainly not necessary even then.
